# Is it possible to use GWT and App Engine together with and android app for commercial use?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt

I tried to give the main idea in the title as good as i could. I am a good programmer in Java and i studied the android sdk. I posted my question here because i believe you can guide me.

Two companies need to send text messages(not sms) in the same android app. The number of users of this app is not known but it could be 500 to 200k. Can Gwt and app engine help me to make it possible. To make it clear i didn't studied these services, but i know if i use them it will have no cost.

The other solution is to make my own server and a web app with another language.
Your answers will save me time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `but i know if i use them it will have no cost`, how did you derive this conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

GWT and App Engine are front end and backend platforms which can be used to build use cases which fit a different need.

App Engine provides a PAAS stack with limitations of hardened sandbox, GWT takes the pain out of Javascript programming but restricts the customization.

If you are using http to communicate with servers then GAE should do the job